# How to giving a specific word to word2vec model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

How to giving a specific word to test a trained word2vec model?

For example

Input "dog", and return nearst word like "cat", "bird" etc..

Thanks!

[word2vec_basic_py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tensor flow example already has a function to compute similarities and show nearest words.
The easiest way is to use that function.

In step 4 after defining valid_examples, you can give your own words.

```
valid_examples = np.random.choice(valid_window, valid_size, replace=False)
num_sampled = 64    # Number of negative examples to sample.

sample_word = "dog";
if sample_word in dictionary:
  sample_index = dictionary[sample_word]
else:
  sample_index = 0  # dictionary['UNK']
valid_examples[0] = sample_index
```

Then you can see the result in first line. For ex, my result was

> Nearest to dog: empower, nephew, stationary, marmoset, wow, kvac,
>   dasyprocta, centaur,